# Click telegram link starts with tg in browser & Open it with telegram desktop

Tags: windows-10, telegram-messenger

When i click on the link below in `FireFox` :

> tg://resolve?domain=BLABLABLA

I face this window :

[image]

When i click `Choose a different application` i face this window :

[image]

`tdesktop.tg` has this error :

[image]

So i chose my telegram exe file manually.
But when i click Telegram.exe to open that link Telegram app opens but it does n't show that link.

I also tried this registry way in windows 10, But it seems it does not work on windows 10 :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tg\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\Jhon\\AppData\\Roaming\\Telegram Desktop\\+12\\Telegram.exe\" -workdir \"C:/Users/Jhon/AppData/Roaming/Telegram Desktop/+12/\" -- \"%1\""
```

Please guide me to fix this issue.